# How do you order the fill-colours within ggplot2 geom_bar

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I am calling the ggplot function

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,fill=category)+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The result is a barplot with bars filled by various colours corresponding to category. However the ordering of the colours is not consistent from bar to bar. Say there is pink, green and blue. Some bars go pink,green,blue from bottom to top and some go green,pink,blue. I don't see any obvious pattern.

How are these orderings chosen? How can I change it? At the very least, how can I make ggplot choose a consistent ordering?

The class of (x,y and category) are (integer,numeric and factor) respectively. If I make category an ordered factor, it does not change this behavior.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame(
  mon = c(
    9L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 11L, 7L,
    12L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 8L,
    7L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 8L
  ),
  gclass = ordered(c(
    "Up-Up", "Down-Down", "Up-Stable", "Stable-Up", "Stable-Down",
    "Stable-Down", "Down-Up", "Stable-Up", "Down-Stable", "Stable-Down",
    "Down-Down", "Down-Down", "Stable-Stable", "Up-Down", "Down-Down",
    "Stable-Up", "Up-Stable", "Stable-Up", "Stable-Down", "Up-Down",
    "Up-Stable", "Up-Down", "Up-Up", "Up-Stable", "Down-Up", "Stable-Stable",
    "Up-Up", "Down-Stable", "Up-Down", "Down-Up", "Stable-Stable",
    "Stable-Stable", "Up-Down", "Up-Down", "Up-Up", "Down-Stable",
    "Stable-Down", "Down-Down", "Down-Up", "Up-Stable"
  )),
  NG = c(
    222614.67, 9998.17, 351162.2, 37357.95, 4140.48, 1878.57, 553.86, 40012.25,
    766.52, 15733.36, 90676.2, 45000.29, 0, 375699.84, 2424.21, 93094.21,
    120547.69, 291.33, 1536.38, 167352.21, 160347.01, 26851.47, 725689.06,
    4500.55, 10644.54, 75132.98, 42676.41, 267.65, 392277.64, 33854.26, 384754.67,
    7195.93, 88974.2, 20665.79, 7185.69, 45059.64, 60576.96, 3564.53, 1262.39,
    9394.15
  )
)

ggplot(data, aes(mon, NG, fill = gclass)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: BTW: Brian confirmed for me that this is in fact a (somewhat longstanding) bug.

Comment: Reader beware - this behavior has unfortunately changed several times in ggplot2's recent history, and some of the examples in the answers don't work anymore.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to specify the `order` aesthetic as well.

```
ggplot(data,aes(mon,NG,fill=gclass,order=gclass))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

This may or may not be a [bug](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/721).

Comment: As of ggplot >= 2.0; `Ignoring unknown aesthetics: order`! (see bellow)

Answer (score 78):

Starting in ggplot2_2.0.0, the `order` aesthetic is no longer available.  To get a graph with the stacks ordered by fill color, you can simply order the dataset by the grouping variable you want to order by.

I often use `arrange` from *dplyr* for this.  Here I'm ordering the dataset by the `fill` factor within the `ggplot` call rather than creating an ordered dataset but either will work fine.

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(arrange(data, gclass), aes(mon, NG, fill = gclass)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This is easily done in base R, of course, using the classic `order` with the extract brackets:

```
ggplot(data[order(data$gclass), ], aes(mon, NG, fill = gclass)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

With the resulting plot in both cases now in the desired order:
[image]

**ggplot2_2.2.0 update**

In ggplot_2.2.0, fill order is based on the order of the factor levels.  The default order will plot the first level at the *top* of the stack instead of the bottom.

If you want the first level at the bottom of the stack you can use `reverse = TRUE` in `position_stack`.  Note you can also use `geom_col` as shortcut for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(mon, NG, fill = gclass)) +
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))
```

Comment: This appears to work fine with stat="identity", but fails with   geom_bar(stat="summary",  
           fun.y=median).  In this case I had to summarise the data and use stat="identity" to get appropriate ordering.  I belive this is new since 2.0

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie It may be that `stat_summary_bin` is the appropriate tool for this.  Have you tried using `stat = "summary_bin"` instead of `stat = "summary"`?

Comment: Ugh, this was quite annoying. Can anyone comment on why the `order` aesthetic was removed? For reference: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1593

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the note and solution!

Comment: For those that may want to change the order of the legend to match the stacking, adding e.g. `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T))` should work nicely.

Answer (score 7):

To order, you must use the `levels` parameter and inform the order. Like this:

```
data$gclass
(data$gclass2 <- factor(data$gclass,levels=sample(levels(data$gclass)))) # Look the difference in the factors order
ggplot(data,aes(mon,NG,fill=gclass2))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the colour using the `scale_fill_` functions. For example:

```
ggplot(dd,aes(mon,NG,fill=gclass)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="blues")
```

To get consistent ordering in the `bars`, then you need to order the data frame:

```
dd = dd[with(dd, order(gclass, -NG)), ]
```

In order to change the ordering of legend, alter the `gclass` factor. So something like:

```
dd$gclass= factor(dd$gclass,levels=sort(levels(dd$gclass), TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Does that look like consistent ordering to you? I'm having the same problem the OP is with his data. Something fishy is going on here.

Comment: @joran Ahh, I see the problem now!

Comment: @Dave31415 I think I've answered the question, however, my understanding of the **why** this work is a bit ropey.

Comment: Ok, I agree, sorting the df seems to work. But this still feels very fishy to me.

Comment: @csgillespie. Thanks. That appears to work but does still seems a little strange. I wonder if the stat="identity" is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since this exchange shows up first for "factor fill order", I will add one more solution, what I believe to be a bit more straight forward, and doesn't require altering your underlying data.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,fill=factor(category, levels = c("Down-Down", "Down-Stable", "Down-Up", "Stable-Down", "Stable-Stable", "Stable-Down", "Up-Down", "Up-Stable", "Up-Up"))) + 
geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE))
```

Or as I prefer, I first create a  variable vector to simplify coding later and make it more easily editable:

```
v_factor_levels <- c("Down-Down", "Down-Stable", "Down-Up", "Stable-Down", "Stable-Stable", "Stable-Down", "Up-Down", "Up-Stable", "Up-Up")

ggplot(data,aes(x,y,fill=factor(category, levels = v_factor_levels)) + 
geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE))
```

You don't need the reverse position element within geom_col(), I keep these as a reminder in case I want to reverse, but you could further simplify by eliminating that.

Comment: For those that want to see neighboring categories better add scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") .

Answer (score 1):

Building on @aosmith 's answer, another way to order the bars, that I found slightly more intuitive is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=mon, y=reorder(NG,gclass), fill = gclass)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

The beauty of the reorder function from the base stats package is that you can apply it in the `reorder(based_on_dimension, y, function)` wherein y is ordered based_on_dimension with a function like sum, mean, etc.