# Control the fill order and groups for a ggplot2 geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
library(ggplot2)


 data <- 
  data.frame(
    group=factor(c("a","c","b","b","c","a")),
    x=c("A","B","C", "D","E","F"),
    y=c(3,2,10,11,4,5)) 

> data
  group x  y
1     a A  3
2     c B  2
3     b C 10
4     b D 11
5     c E  4
6     a F  5

#And plot this:
ggplot(data)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=group, order=group),
           stat="identity",
           position="dodge")+
  coord_flip()
```

This gives a figure where x is plotted according to factor levels:
[image]

But how can one reorder x according to a custom order of the `group` variable and at the same time arrange within `group` according to say descending `y`. For instance if I want to plot first "c" (red), then "a" (green) and then "b" (blue) groups, the plot order of the x-axis (`x` variable) would be: E, B, F, A, D, C. Note this may have resemblance to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251816/how-do-you-order-the-fill-colours-within-ggplot2-geom-bar) SO question.

Comment: Why your data frame has a column x with values `best`,`good` etc and in the display it has `A`,`B`,`C` ??

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel: Good question, gives no meaning. I mixed two data set up and stupidly went for lunch. I have update it!

Comment: Thks for the clarification!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need first to format your dataframe without `factor`. Then you need to define the x column as `factor` but with order depending on `y` minimum per `group`. This specific ordering you want needs to be specified in `levels` argument.

Here we go:

```
data <- 
  data.frame(
    group=c("a","c","b","b","c","a"),
    x=c("A","B","C", "D","E","F"),
    y=c(3,2,10,11,4,5)) 

data$x = with(data, factor(x, levels=x[order(ave(y, group, FUN=min),y)]))

ggplot(data, aes(x, y, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]