# Reorder columns by value while maintaining group order

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

My data (reproduced below) contain three variables, `Tools` (categorical variable), `Proficiency` (value column) and `Category` (grouping column).
I would like to sort the columns based on descending order of `Proficiency` value, while maintaining separation of `Category` groups, and without using `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` (because I am using `coord_flip`). Reproducible data is below. To sort by `Category`, I specify the levels of `Tools` based on the `Category` factor.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(Tools = structure(c(1L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("Tool1", "Tool7", "Tool8", "Tool9", "Tool4", 
"Tool5", "Tool10", "Tool2", "Tool3", "Tool6"), class = "factor"), 
    Proficiency = c(3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2), Category = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Category1", 
    "Category2", "Category3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

df1$Tools <- factor(df1$Tools, levels = df1$Tools[order(df1$Category)])

ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = Tools, y = Proficiency, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df1$Tools)))
```

This produces the below plot, which is obviously not grouped in descending order of `Proficiency` value.

[image: first_image]

One way to accomplish the desired grouping and sorting is by using `facet_grid()` and reordering `Tools` based on `Proficiency` within the `aes` call:

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = reorder(Tools, -Proficiency), y = Proficiency, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~ Category, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image: image2]

However, I would like to use `coord_flip` for this plot. Unfortunately, `coord_flip` does not seem to work well with `facet_grid` (github issues [one](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1393), [two](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1492))
.

Predictably, sorting by `Proficiency` without using `facet_grid` causes the plot to override the `Category` groups.

[image: image3]

My desired output is the above image, where the `Tools` are sorted firstly by `Category`, and secondarily by `Proficiency`. Any help is much appreciated.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208873/control-the-fill-order-and-groups-for-a-ggplot2-geom-bar?rq=1) looked promising, but applying a similar approach here didn't work for me; the below manipulation just set up the plot for ordering via `Proficiency`:

```
df1$Tools <- with(df1, factor(Tools, levels=Tools[order(ave(Proficiency, Category, FUN=min),Proficiency)]))`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph ?

Comment: @RonakShah that question relates to ordering by just one variable, whereas I'm looking to order based on two variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to arrange your dataframe into the desired order and set the factor levels of `Tools` with that order.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>%
  arrange(desc(Category), desc(Proficiency)) %>%
  mutate(Tools = factor(Tools, levels = Tools)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Tools, y = Proficiency, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use function `fct_infreq( )`

```
ggplot(df2, aes(fct_infreq(x),y))+
 geom_col()
```