# ggplot stacked bar reorders legend is as defined in factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my filled areas ordered in the same way as my legend. The factor `Antwort` is already ordered correctly and colors in the legend are correct. However, the order and the colors in the graph are completely jumbled. Apparently the bars get reordered in alphabetical order.
[image]

*dataset:*

```
gdata <- structure(list(Antwort=c("Eher zutreffend","Trifft eher nicht 
zu","Trifft überhaupt nicht zu","Trifft voll zu","Weder noch","Eher 
zutreffend","Trifft eher nicht zu","Trifft überhaupt nicht zu","Trifft 
voll zu","Weder noch","Eher zutreffend","Trifft eher nicht zu","Trifft 
überhaupt nicht zu","Trifft voll zu","Weder noch","Eher  
zutreffend","Trifft eher nicht zu","Trifft überhaupt nicht zu","Trifft 
voll zu","Weder noch","Eher zutreffend","Trifft eher nicht zu","Trifft 
überhaupt nicht zu","Trifft voll zu","Weder 
noch"),val=c(307,441,55,54,195,481,290,12,33,236,432,299,1,46,274,405,357,
27,53,210,506,51,20,399,76),label=c("Extraversion","Extraversion",
"Extraversion","Extraversion","Extraversion","Agreeableness",
"Agreeableness","Agreeableness","Agreeableness","Agreeableness",
"Conscientiousness","Conscientiousness","Conscientiousness",
"Conscientiousness","Conscientiousness","Neurotic","Neurotic",
"Neurotic","Neurotic","Neurotic","Openness","Openness","Openness",
"Openness","Openness")),.Names=c("Antwort","val","label"),
class="data.frame",row.names=1:25)
```

And here is my code:

```
five = c('Trifft voll zu', 'Eher zutreffend', 'Weder noch', 'Trifft eher nicht zu', 'Trifft überhaupt nicht zu')
gdata$Antwort <- factor(gdata$Antwort,levels=five)

ggplot(data=gdata, aes(x=label, y=val)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",colour="black",position="stack",aes(fill=Antwort)) +
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4169e1","#808080","#d3d3d3","#808080","#ff4500")) +
 coord_flip()
```

Do you have a hint what I do wrong?

**Update:**

I didn't find a solution using levels. Apparently the string based levels got reordered alphabetically for the fill every time. My solution was brute force. I used integers as factors for fill and assigned labels manually using `scale_y_discrete(labels=five,breaks=NULL)`.

A hint to all who have to work with Lickert scales. the `HH` package for R provides quick and beautiful visualizations for such integer based scales.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. I will suggest that you should try ordered factor. Then it should give the colors in the order in which you order the factor.

Comment: I thought the `factor(gdata$Antwort, levels=five)` does the reordering?

Comment: Any help in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186436/order-stacked-bar-graph-in-ggplot

Comment: For making ordered factor, you need to use ordered argument e.g. 
`factor(gdata$Antwort, levels=five, ordered = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried including `ordered=TRUE` but it didn't improve. How can I make the code reproducible for you?

Comment: It's not easy to help you as you did not provided some data. But you could try to simply add a `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = levels(gdata$Antwort))`

Comment: I added the dataset for reproduction. I tried `ordered=TRUE` but it sadly didn't help.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to order the dataset in the order you want the bars as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34637703/2461552)