# Barplot bars going the wrong direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a biology graduate student learning R. I was hoping someone could help me have the bars go horizontally in the opposite direction (the blue portion should start at 0 and the red at the 100 end of the scale).

Graph with bars in the wrong direction

[image]

Here is the data

```
my_species <- c('apomict_2-17-17_compreh', 'apomict_2-17-17_compreh', 'apomict_2-17-17_compreh', 'apomict_2-17-17_compreh', 'parthenogen_2-17-17_compreh', 'parthenogen_2-17-17_compreh', 'parthenogen_2-17-17_compreh', 'parthenogen_2-17-17_compreh', 'sexual_2-9-17', 'sexual_2-9-17', 'sexual_2-9-17', 'sexual_2-9-17')
my_species <- factor(my_species)
my_species <- factor(my_species,levels(my_species)[c(length(levels(my_species)):1)]) # reorder your species here just by changing the values in the vector :
my_percentage <- c(36.3, 56.3, 2.6, 4.8, 42.2, 50.6, 2.4, 4.8, 56.0, 19.9, 6.7, 17.4)
my_values <- c(522, 811, 38, 69, 608, 729, 35, 68, 806, 286, 96, 252)
category <- c(rep(c("S","D","F","M"),c(1)))
category <-factor(category)
category = factor(category,levels(category)[c(4,1,2,3)])
df = data.frame(my_species,my_percentage,my_values,category)
```

Here is the code:

```
# Load the required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library("grid")

# !!! CONFIGURE YOUR PLOT HERE !!! 
# Output
#my_output <- paste("/home/loki/","busco_figure.png",sep="/") 
my_width <- 20
my_height <- 15
my_unit <- "cm"

# Colors
my_colors <- c("#56B4E9", "#3492C7", "#F0E442", "#F04442")
# Bar height ratio
my_bar_height <- 0.75

# Legend
my_title <- "BUSCO Assessment Results"

# Font
my_family <- "sans"
my_size_ratio <- 1


# Code to produce the graph
labsize = 1
if (length(levels(my_species)) > 10){
 labsize = 0.66
}
print("Plotting the figure ...")


figure <- ggplot() +       
  geom_bar(aes(y = my_percentage, x = my_species, fill = category), data = df, stat="identity", width=my_bar_height) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_gray(base_size = 8) + 
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = c("100","80","60","40","20","0"), breaks = c(100,80,60,40,20,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("100","80","60","40","20","0"), breaks = c(100,80,60,40,20,0)) +
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = c("100","80","60","40","20","0"), breaks = c(0,20,40,60,80,100)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors,labels =c(" Complete (C) and single-copy (S)  ",
                                                 " Complete (C) and duplicated (D)",
                                                 " Fragmented (F)  ",
                                                 " Missing (M)")) +   
  ggtitle(my_title) + 
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("\n%BUSCOs") + 

  theme(plot.title = element_text(family=my_family, colour = "black", size = rel(2.2)*my_size_ratio, face = "bold")) + 
  theme(legend.position="top",legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(family=my_family, size = rel(1.2)*my_size_ratio)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color="#FFFFFF", fill="white")) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(family=my_family, colour = "black", size = rel(1.66)*my_size_ratio)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family=my_family, colour = "black", size = rel(1.66)*my_size_ratio)) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size=1*my_size_ratio, colour = "black")) + 
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(.85, "cm")) + 
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour="white", size = 0)) + 
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour="#222222")) + 
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0.4, "cm")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family=my_family, size=rel(1.2)*my_size_ratio)) + 

  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL))) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))

  for(i in rev(c(1:length(levels(my_species))))){
    detailed_values <- my_values[my_species==my_species[my_species==levels(my_species)[i]]]
    total_buscos <- sum(detailed_values)
    figure <- figure + 
    annotate("text", label=paste("C:", detailed_values[1] + detailed_values[2], " [S:", detailed_values[1], ", D:", detailed_values[2], "], F:", detailed_values[3], ", M:", detailed_values[4], ", n:", total_buscos, sep=""), 
             y=3, x = i, size = labsize*4*my_size_ratio, colour = "black", hjust=0, family=my_family)
  }

my_output="~/temp.png"
ggsave(figure, file=my_output, width = my_width, height = my_height, unit = my_unit)
print("Done")
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34637703/2109767.  Looking at your code I think that answer should achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know!

Comment: I'm sorry but that post did not seem to achieve what I want (unless I just couldn't implement it correctly). I'm new to R and most of this R script was generated by the busco python script. I'm just wanting the entire bars including colored components to flip horizontally.

Comment: No problem, I was trying to point you in the right direction because I didn't have time to provide a full answer.  Please see my answer below, hopefully it helps you create your plot as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see `?position_stack`:

> position_fill() and position_stack() automatically stack values in
>   reverse order of the group aesthetic, which for bar charts is usually
>   defined by the fill aesthetic (the default group aesthetic is formed
>   by the combination of all discrete aesthetics except for x and y).
>   This default ensures that bar colours align with the default legend.

In order to change the stacking direction, you simply need to add `position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` to `geom_bar`:

```
figure <- ggplot() +       
    geom_bar(
        aes(y = my_percentage, x = my_species, fill = category),
        data = df, stat="identity", width=my_bar_height,
        position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
...
```

[image]

If you don't want to use `position_stack`, you would have to change factor level and You also have to set filling color breaks to maintain the same legend order.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reorder the factor levels in order for ggplot2 to know what to do. Here is an example of that (note I had to reorder the labels and colors as well):

```
...
# Colors
my_colors <- c( "#F04442", "#F0E442", "#3492C7", "#56B4E9")
...
df$category = ordered(df$category, levels = c("M", "F", "D", "S"))

figure <- ggplot(data = df[order(df$category, decreasing = F),]) +       
  geom_bar(aes(y = my_percentage, x = my_species, fill = category), stat="identity", width=my_bar_height) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_gray(base_size = 8) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("100","80","60","40","20","0"), breaks = c(100,80,60,40,20,0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors,labels =c(" Missing (M)", 
                                                 " Fragmented (F)  ",
                                                 " Complete (C) and duplicated (D)",
                                                 " Complete (C) and single-copy (S)  ")) +   
...
```

Comment: @mt1022's answer is more straightforward, but I figured I would leave this here as it still presents another way of achieving this.