# Sorted values in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have a following code, where I would like to do a bar plot from XXX dataset, where X2 variable is sorted:

```
XXX %>% arrange(desc(X2)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X2)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =  0.75) + 
   coord_flip()
```

Why it does not work? I have the same plot like without arrange(desc(X2)). I know already how to do the arrangement, but I would like to understand why it is not an appropriate solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you order the fill-colours within ggplot2 geom\_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251816/how-do-you-order-the-fill-colours-within-ggplot2-geom-bar)

Comment: RLave, I said that I know how to do it. I would like to understand why it does not work. So I think it is not a duplicated question.

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/721

Comment: From the answer to that other question.

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your actual output? `arrange` shouldn't affect the order of the bars in the plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrange()` just sorts the *data* but ggplot does do it's own sorting. This is convenient if X2 is numeric but might be somewhat unexpected for text. The trick is to define X2 in a way, that the natural order of X2 is the order *you* want. If you want for example X2 ordered by decreasing frequencies, you could write your own function e.g.:

```
factor_freq <- function(x, decreasing = TRUE) {
  counts <- sort(table(x), decreasing = decreasing)
  factor(x, levels=names(counts))
}
```

and then

```
XXX %>% mutate(X2 = factor_freq(X2)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X2)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =  0.75) + 
   coord_flip()
```

should produce the desired plot.