# Custom reorder histogram fill categories in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2 the histogram fill categories are ordered alphabetically. I would like to assign a custom order to my fill as such:

```
cust_order <- c("Goal", "Shot on target", "Shot blocked", "Wide shot")
```

This is different from reordering the colors as described here: [How do you order the fill-colours within ggplot2 geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251816/how-do-you-order-the-fill-colours-within-ggplot2-geom-bar).Code so far...

```
shot_df %>% filter(Team == "Team A") %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = xG, fill=Type)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.10)
```

And the final (alphabetical) output:
[image: sample histogram]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please `dput(shot_df )` and paste the result in your question in order to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `factor` with `levels` in the customer order `vector` and then it should work

```
shot_df$Type<- factor(shot_df$Type, levels = cust_order)
```

Comment: Why was this marked duplicate? The linked answer is not what I asked. It doesn't point to a solution that allows you to custom order your groupings. And the marked answer in the other one uses a deprecated function. How is that helpful? I don't know who marked it as a duplicate but @akrun should get credit and people should be able to see a concise answer to this specific question.

Comment: @seansteele it is marked by somebody else as dupe. Not by me. thanks

Comment: @mrflick I have edited my question to make clear that is different from the one offered as already answering my question. Can you please reopen and allow akrun's answer stand? Thank you.